# How to pass a value from a Jquery submit function to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, submit, form-submit

I have a jQuery function which I call when I click a button and which submits a form:

```
function SubmitFormData() {
        $("#myForm").submit(); // Submit the form
    }
```

and in PHP I would like to check for "if form as been submited AND if value is true". Without using Jquery, just submitting to PHP I do it like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['accepted'])){
   ///submit to database
 }
```

is there a way to set this variable: `$_POST['accepted']`? so I would keep the if statement as it is.

Answer (score 0):

As Jquery being the Javascript framework it is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language.to pass the data from JS(Jquery) to a PHP file you will need to make an ajax call to the PHP page and post the data.

For more details regarding jquery [Click Here](https://api.jquery.com/).